# Drupal: Create a unique selector for admin styles?

Tags: php, drupal, admin, preprocessor, theming

I'd like to style some components differently in the admin. How could I generate a unique id/class on the body element so I could style admin elements separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by looking at the [admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) module. It helps you to create an admin theme and other AI improvements. I found that using the [rubik](http://code.developmentseed.org/rubik/) theme.

You can also just put a class on admin pages, by [checking the first argument](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg/6) in a [preprocess function](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_page/6). For all admin pages they the first arg should be `admin`. The preprocess function should be in your theme's template.php file, and named according to your theme's name.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the location of the preprocess function and how to "check the first argument"?